# Evitar que DIV altere um tamanho definido

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando montar uma página HTML para imprimir uma etiqueta com 80mm x 40mm. Ela está esta dando certo, porém quando o nome da pessoa é muito grande a etiqueta perde o alinhamento, consumindo 2 etiquetas.

Preciso travar o tamanho da `div`, e se o texto for maior ele tem que ser resumido e não alterar o tamanho da mesma.

Exemplo do código funcionando:

```html
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; width: 80mm; height: 40mm; background: #ccc;">

  <!-- Nome Cliente -->
  <div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
    <b>RAFAEL VILELA</b>
  </div>

  <!-- Endereço -->
  <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;">
    BOA ESPERANÇA - MG<br> RUA SÃO TIAGO - 298
  </div>

  <!-- Volumes -->
  <div style="height: 15mm; text-align: center; line-height: 15mm; font-size: 18px;">
    <b>Vol.: 1 / 3</b>
  </div>

  <!-- Nome Cliente -->
  <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;">
    CON. JOÃO ALGUSTO<br> 19/10/2018 - (11:20)
  </div>
</div>
```

Agora um exemplo da como fica desalinhado com o nome grande.

```html
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; width: 80mm; height: 40mm; background: #ccc;">

  <!-- Nome Cliente -->
  <div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
    <b>RAFAEL VILELA FARIA BORGES DE ALMEIDA TESTE NOME GRANDE</b>
  </div>

  <!-- Endereço -->
  <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;">
    BOA ESPERANÇA - MG<br> RUA SÃO TIAGO - 298
  </div>


  <!-- Volumes -->
  <div style="height: 15mm; text-align: center; line-height: 15mm; font-size: 18px;">
    <b>Vol.: 1 / 3</b>
  </div>

  <!-- Nome Cliente -->
  <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;">
    CON. JOÃO ALGUSTO<br> 19/10/2018 - (11:20)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Hugo Borges, o css tem que ser in-line ou tem algum arquivo css externo?

Comment: Pode ser externo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar CSS na linha do nome do cliente para não ultrapassar mais de uma linha, outra coisa importante é adicionar "display: block" no css da sua div principal tornando essa div com uma altura fixa especificada.

```html
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; width: 80mm; height: 4cm; background: #ccc; display:block; display: block">

      <!-- Nome Cliente -->
      <div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
        <b style="max-width: 80mm; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden !important; text-overflow: ellipsis; display: inline-block;">RAFAEL VILELA FARIA BORGES DE ALMEIDA TESTE NOME GRANDE</b>
      </div>

      <!-- Endereço -->
      <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;">
        BOA ESPERANÇA - MG<br> RUA SÃO TIAGO - 298
      </div>


      <!-- Volumes -->
      <div style="height: 15mm; text-align: center; line-height: 15mm; font-size: 18px;">
        <b>Vol.: 1 / 3</b>
      </div>

      <!-- Nome Cliente -->
      <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;">
        CON. JOÃO ALGUSTO<br> 19/10/2018 - (11:20)
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode tentar usar o max-width para limitar o tamanho maximo da div para nao querbrar e ultrapassar o limite do parent dela e desconfigurar a pagina. 
Para reduzir o nome voce pode utilizar word-break: break-all, que vai quebrar a linha do texto. A minha referencia ,caso queira testar online, é o W3Schools os links da minha ajuda são [Max-width](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp) 
 e [Word_break](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

```html
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; width: 80mm; height: 40mm; background: #ccc;">

  <!-- Nome Cliente -->

  <div style="page-break-inside: avoid; max-width:80mm">
    <b style="word-break: break-all">RAFAEL VILELA FARIA BORGES DE ALMEIDA TESTE NOME GRANDE</b>
  </div>

  <!-- Endereço -->
  <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;">
    BOA ESPERANÇA - MG<br> RUA SÃO TIAGO - 298
  </div>


  <!-- Volumes -->
  <div style="height: 15mm; text-align: center; line-height: 15mm; font-size: 18px;">
    <b>Vol.: 1 / 3</b>
  </div>

  <!-- Nome Cliente -->
  <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;">
    CON. JOÃO ALGUSTO<br> 19/10/2018 - (11:20)
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado